# How to make content in an edit Text bold without making the hint bold?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to make content in an `editText` bold without making the hint bold? I have tried 
`android:textStyle="bold"`. But it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether it is a best solution, but highlighting text may help

http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext